# I am trying to make checkbox act like radio button with angularjs

Tags: angularjs, checklist-model

I am trying to make checkbox work like radio button.
When one checkbox is checked another checkbox should automatically uncheck.

Can anyone show me how to do it.

[Example](http://plnkr.co/edit/VScXRhYSpbZujH8qJRf6?p=preview)

```
<label ng-repeat="role in roles">
    <input id="{{role.text}}" type="checkbox" onbeforesave="validateRequired($data)" 
           ng-click="$last&&mytest(checked)" ng-disabled="user.text"  
           checklist-model="user.roles" checklist-value="role.text" 
           ng-init="user.roles=false"/>
               {{role.text}} &nbsp;&nbsp;
</label>
```

Comment: Can't use just use radio buttons?

Comment: No tats the issue :(

Comment: what is the use case to change the checkbox to radio button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// HTML in INPUT
ng-true-value="{{role.id}}" ng-false-value=""  ng-model="result.id"
// Controller 
$scope.result = {};
```

You can check $index like that

```
     $scope.check = function (index) {
                $scope.type = index;        
            }
    $scope.type === $scope.result.id
>>>>> true
```

its working :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Mike86 in html line iam using  checklist-model="user.roles" not ng-model="". Will it work with the checklist-model?

Comment: its not diference jsut add my code to input and controller and try it its working :) Please accept answer to useful bro

Comment: Its now working @Mike86, can you please show it in the plunker I have attached. I am defiantly gonna accept your answer bro.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/5qG1O1opTjGCS6lByf6R?p=preview Its working your code man please vote up